# Loading a file complains about file not found in a specific path, but filesystem is read-only so can't copy

Tags: linux, drivers, filesystems, embedded-linux

I am loading a wifi module which is sitting in `/usr/lib/modules/<kernel_version>/extra` by running `modprobe <module_name.ko>` but it errors out saying `modprobe: FATAL: Module <module_name.ko> not found in directory /lib/modules/<kernel_version>`.

That's true, but when I try to copy the module into `/lib/modules/<kernel_version>`, it complains how it's a Read-only file system.

I tried running `mount -o remount /` to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Run `modprobe module_name` in stead of `modprobe module_name.ko`.

Comment: it errors out: `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert <module_name>': Invalid argument`

Comment: in the `dmesg` output, I see `Fail to register pcie driver`. Is that causing the driver to be not loaded?

Comment: "could not insert <module_name>"?  I find that hard to believe.

Comment: do you see the failure message in `dmesg` output being the cause?

Comment: What is the real message?